# How can I make bookmarks automatically be saved to the bookmarks bar in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bookmarks

How would I go about making it so that my bookmarks are automatically saved to the bookmarks bar when I press the bookmarks button in Firefox like happens in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for that in Firefox. But with an addon like [Add Bookmark Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-bookmark-here-2/) (I use it myself too), you can add your bookmarks to the menu bar by pressing Ctrl+D, and pressing done to save. In Firefox the default option is to save bookmarks in the "Unsorted Bookmarks" folder, and you can change the location by pressing again in the star, and changing the location. Other than this two options, I don't know any other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Save my tabs!
An open source browser addon/extension to bookmark at once all open tabs to a folder in the Bookmarks Toolbar.
Now it includes an auto-save feature.

https://github.com/salvoventura/save-my-tabs

https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/save-all-my-tabs/

tested on Firefox 103.0.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).